# gtlfjsx model error: memory access out of bounds, Decoding failed

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gltf, react-three-fiber

I'm facing this error as showen in image while rendering this [floating-shoe](https://github.com/drcmda/floating-shoe) using gltfjsx example and i don't know the real source of bug, any solution or even a hint.
The model was working 100% then i was working on an other component ib the same app without touching the model code then suddenly the error occured...I tried to reinstall the project file from this repos without any other componenet just the shoe model boilerplate, and the same error occured.

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNGRR.png)

Comment: You'll need to share running, reproducible example of the issue to get help with this - a demo or a codepen perhaps.

Comment: This appears to be a software bug, I see you've reported it at https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx/issues/132 — this question can likely be closed?